# How to make UDP based connection in node.js

Tags: node.js

In node.js documentation it is specifically stated that

"Class: net.Server#
Added in: v0.1.90
This class is used to create a TCP or local server."

Is it possible to create a UDP based connection rather than TCP using node.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. See [UDP / Datagram Sockets on the Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/dgram.html).

Comment: Yes, Thanks a lot!!